# Making Thingworx REST API commands in a C environment

Tags: c, rest, arduino, thingworx

I am currently trying to make PUT statements to a Thingworx server to change properties. Does anybody know how to do this in a C environment more specifically for a Arduino UNO.

Comment: What did you try ? Question on SO, must show some effort that you put into fixing this problem yourself. Link, code whatever that show you are not a [vampire helper](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm).

Comment: I would like to know if it's possible to do the same call using the C SDK. Seems silly to use the REST API separate from the C SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ethernet / Ethernet 2 library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet) in order to make RESTful API calls from Arduino to a Thingworx server through ethernet or wifi shields.

Here is a sample (ethernet) implementation for your reference:

```
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <EthernetClient.h>
#include <EthernetUdp2.h>
#include <util.h>

IPAddress _ip(192, 168, 1, 12); // Client (Arduino) IP address
byte _mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x11, 0x3C, 0x69}; // Arduino mac address
char _server[] = "192.168.1.10"; // Server IP address
int _port = 9200; // Server port number
EthernetClient _client;

void setup() {    
  Ethernet.begin(_mac, _ip);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Local IP: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  if (_client.connect(_server, _port)) {
    Serial.println("SUCCESS: Connected to the server!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("ERROR: Connection failed to the server!");
    return;
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {       
  // JSON formatted data package including sample UID and newValue 
  String payload = "{\"uid\": " + String(uid) + ", " +
                   "\"data\": " + String(newValue) + "}";

  String url = "/my-api/updatedata"; // API url hosted on the server

  // Finally, make an API call: PUT request
  _client.print("PUT " + url + " HTTP/1.1 \r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/json \r\n" +
    "Content-Length: " + payload.length() + " \r\n" +
    "\r\n" + payload);

  delay(500); // Give the network some time

  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and 
  // print them to Serial to validate your API call
  while (_client.available()) {
    String reply = _client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(reply);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thingworx provides the "C Edge SDK" for communicating with the Thingworx platform. The SDK provides utility functions (`twApi_WriteProperty`) to read/write properties on a bound Thing.

Link to the SDK documentation below:

- http://support.ptc.com/help/thingworx_hc/thingworx_edge_sdks_ems/#page/thingworx_edge_sdks_ems%2Fc_sdk%2Fc_csdk_general_introduction.html%23

Specific link to the property update:

- http://support.ptc.com/help/thingworx_hc/thingworx_edge_sdks_ems/#page/thingworx_edge_sdks_ems%2Fc_sdk%2Fc_csdk_write_property.html%23

Comment: quite useless. Second link just points to the C SDK Edge functions which won't be used anyhow when doing TWX related REST calls.